# average timespan conversion error

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2015, average, timespan

I have some data in a .csv file that looks like this:

```
1, task1, 00:00:02.0000000
1, task2, 00:00:00.3529381
1, task3, 00:00:01.1604731
1, task4, 00:00:00.1413738
```

The third column are TimeSpans.  I need to calculate the average, min, max, etc on them.  The problem I am having in trying the online methods is that its coming back as 0.  I've tried:

```
public Log(string a_action, string a_time, string a_executionTime, string a_studentLogin)
{
    Action = a_action;
    Time = a_time;
    ExecutionTime_s = a_executionTime;
    ExecutionTime_ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0", @"h\:m",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    ExecutionTime_l = Convert.ToInt64(ExecutionTime_ts.TotalMilliseconds);

    ExecutionTime_d = (double)ExecutionTime_ts.TotalMilliseconds;
}

public void Calc()
{
    List<Log> logList = CSVToList.GetList();

    double doubleAverageTicks = logList.Average(timeSpan => timeSpan.ExecutionTime_d);
    long longAverageTicks = Convert.ToInt64(doubleAverageTicks);

    TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan(longAverageTicks);
}
```

Suggestions appreciated..also my linq sux

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(doubleAverageTicks);
```